# How to validate Microsoft.Web.Administration ObjectState

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5, microsoft.web.administration

Hello here is my csharp code to get all sites from the IIS Server

```
List<IISObject> iisSiteList = new List<IISObject>();

ServerManager serverMgr = new ServerManager();
SiteCollection sitecollection = serverMgr.Sites;

try
{

    foreach (var site in sitecollection)
    {

        string SiteState = site.State.ToString();

        if (site.Name != "Default Web Site")
        {

            IISObject issObject = new IISObject() { Name = site.Name, SiteId = site.Id, State = SiteState };
            iisSiteList.Add(issObject);

        }
    }

    return iisSiteList;

}

catch (Exception e)
{
    return e.Message.ToString();
}
```

The above code giving me the following error

> ('The object identifier does not represent a valid object. (Exception from '
> 'HRESULT: 0x800710D8)')

The reason of this error is one of the site has unknown state, so if I simply comment this line **string SiteState = site.State.ToString();** then it start working.

Now I need help that how I can validate ObjectState before assign it to a variable. I tried this

```
if (site.State)
{
  string SiteState = site.State.toString();
}
else
{
  string SiteState = "unknown"
}
```

Then Visual Studio showing this

> CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'Microsfot.Web.Administration.ObjectState' to 'bool'

Now would you please help me how to fix this

Answer (score 2):

[Microsoft.Web.Administration ObjectState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration.objectstate?view=iis-dotnet) is an enum type, you need to check it like `site.State != ObjectState.Unknown`, you can use the following example as a reference:

```
if (site.State != ObjectState.Unknown)
{
  string SiteState = site.State.ToString();
}
else
{
string SiteState = "unknown";
}
```

Comment: hi samwu, thanks for the help